# exif_read_data() function not extract any gps info from images

Tags: php, gps, jpeg, exif, samsung-mobile

I use function `exif_read_data` to extract form jpg gps info, which for all images works. However, my client has a samsung tablet and for all photos done with this, I can't get any gps info. For example in windows proprieties of photo I can see the photo really does have gps info. Why? Is there anyone else who has had this problem? The foto is here https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6q3iduky7vut6l/1.jpg?dl=0

The code is simple:

```
 $exif = exif_read_data('1.jpg'); 
  print_r($exif);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution might be to use

```
$img = new \Imagick(DSC01386.jpg);
$allProp = $img->getImageProperties();
$exifProp = $img->getImageProperties("exif:*");
```

[The Imagick class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php), is quite powerful class (rotations etc).

Comment: To me, your answer looks somewhat incomplete. How would one go about extracting the gps info from `$exifProp`?